# Spring bean overriding does not throw exception when default settings is not allowing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have the below configuration class.

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }
}
```

I am creating object mapper (Jackson) bean to use as a model mapper but I believe Spring must throw BeanDefinitionOverrideException as I am overriding ObjectMapper. I know this exception is added and thrown in such cases after Spring Boot 2.1 and am using 2.4.x versions.

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=false // default config
```

I am wondering why I am not getting such exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the [`@ConditionalOnMissingBean`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/3c5c5d95759aa4a967e5017c57f7144bd0349e9c/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration.java#L101) in the default `ObjectMapper` bean configuration provided by spring-boot , it will only define and configure a default `ObjectMapper` bean  if you do not define one by yourself.

Now as you define an `ObjectMapper` , it causes spring-boot stop defining the default one. So in the end you just have one `ObjectMapper` bean and hence `BeanDefinitionOverrideException` will not happen.

If you create another `@Configuration` and define one more `ObjectMapper` with the same name , you should produce `BeanDefinitionOverrideException` :

```java
@Configuration
@Import(BeanConfig2.class)
public class BeanConfig {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }
}

@Configuration
public class BeanConfig2 {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly. It can be seen in `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration`